# Loading posts via AJAX with post navigation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to load my posts with AJAX and with the loaded post, have ajax-based post-navigation.

My question is: How should I make the post pagination to post footer. (check [linked image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywGD7.png) if it is hard to understand what I mean). So when you navigate from the footer of the currently opened post, you straight open the previous or the next project and it will be opened to the same div#single-project as the one you navigated from.

Can I use the same functions.php Function to send pagination data, or should I make a new function where I send pagination data.

functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_load_post', 'working_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load_post', 'working_function' );

    function working_function() {
        check_ajax_referer( 'nonce', 'security' );
        if ( isset( $_POST['id'] ) 
          && 'post' == get_post_type( $_POST['id'] )
          && 'publish' == get_post_status( $_POST['id'] ) ) {
            $id = (int)$_POST['id'];
            global $post;
            $post = get_post( $id );
            $prev_post = get_previous_post();
            $next_post = get_next_post();

            $data = array();
            $data['article'] = '<h1>' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $post->post_title ) . '</h1>';
            $data['article'] .= apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );
            $data['article'] .= '<footer>' . '<nav class="navigation pagination">' . '<div class="nav-links">' . '<div class="nav-previous">' . '<a nav-id=""'  . 'href="' . apply_filters('the_permalink', get_permalink($prev_post->ID)) . '" rel="prev">Previous Article</a>' . '</div>' . '<div class="nav-next">' . '<a href="' . apply_filters('the_permalink', get_permalink($next_post->ID)) . '" rel="prev">Next Article</a>' . '</div' . '</div>' . '</nav>' . '</footer>';
            wp_send_json_success($data);
        } else  {
            wp_send_json_error( 'Error' );
        }
        wp_die();
    }
```

Main js:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', 'a.link-to', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            $.ajax({
                url: ajax_url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    action: 'load_post',
                    security: nonce,
                    id: id
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        var article = $(data.data.article);
                        $('.single-project').html(article);
                        $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: ($("#single-project").first().offset().top)
                        }, 400);
                    } else {
                        console.log(data.data);
                    }
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log('Error');
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

To my main js-file, I must do new click function, something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.nav-links a', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow got it working. I changed it that the a.link-to -click-function calls loadProject function and sends the ID to call. Then the loadProject function calls ajax with the correct ID.

I changed the behaviour of the previous and next post links. Now when clicked, they call paginateProject function with the ID of the post. paginateProject function calls again the loadProject function.

```
function loadProject(projectID) {
    "use strict";
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajax.ajax_url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'load_post',
            security: nonce,
            id: projectID
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                var article = $(data.data.article);
                    jQuery(this).html(article);
            } else {
                console.log(data.data);
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error_loadProject');
        }
    });
}

function paginateProject(slug) {
    "use strict";
    var projectID = slug;
    console.log('Clicked onclick="paginateProject(' + projectID + ')"');
    loadProject(projectID);
}

    $(document).on('click', 'a.link-to', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var projectID = $(this).data('id');
        loadProject(projectID);
        console.log('Clicked a.link-to ' + projectID);
    });
```